# Enviar un string con un (salto de línea) por request en java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Tengo un *servlet* desde el cual quiero enviar un mensaje con un salto de línea por *request* de la siguiente manera:

```
request.setAttribute("msjok", "Linea 1.\nLinea 2.");
```

y luego en un *jsp*, mediante *EL*, intento mostrarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
${msjok}
```

El mensaje esta llegando pero solo me está mostrando "*Linea 1.Linea 2.*", sin el salto de línea que intento agregar.
Entonces, ¿es correcta la forma en la que estoy intetando agregar un salto de línea al texto? y sino, ¿que forma es la correcta?.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba agregando &lt;br/&gt;  que eso se traduce como un  <br/>

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Puede servirme como alternativa, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que para el navegador el salto de línea no existe. No lo usa para nada. El navegador muestra la página en función del HTML, no de saltos de línea.

Si miras el código fuente de la página HTML verás que el salto de línea esta ahí<sup>1</sup>, aunque al ver la página web no lo puedas notar.

Si quieres mostrar un salto de línea, lo más sencillo es hacer

```
request.setAttribute("msjok", "Linea 1.<br/>Linea 2.");
```

y luego

```
${msjok}
```

Sin embargo, para mi gusto es algo feo mezclar HTML con los atributos. Para un caso esporádico puede aceptarse, pero si vas a hacerlo mucho preferiría pasar el atributo como una lista e iterar con JSTL/JSF

```
request.setAttribute("msjok", new String[]{"Linea 1.", "Linea 2."});
```

y

```
<c:forEach var="lineaMsjok" items="${msjok}">
   <c:out value="${lineaMsjok}" /><br/>
</c:forEach
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
Me fijé y en el código fuente de la página no aparece el "_\n_" por lo que me parece que el problema viene por otro lado..
Y si, pense en utilizar estas dos opciones que me recomiendas, pero el "_<br>_" dentro del String me parecia desprolijo como bien decis y quería evitar la lista de mensajes pero quizás termine haciendo esto.
Igual me sigue quedando la duda de porque el "_/n_" desaparece.

Comment: La duda te la respondió el compañero, en paginas web HTML, `/n`  no se reconoce como comando para salto de linea.

Comment: Con tu código inicial, en el código fuente del HTML no vas a ver `\n` tal cual si no que simplemente vas a ver que `Linea 1.` y `Linea 2.` no aparecen en la misma fila (de nuevo, esto **en el código fuente**); `\n` es un caracter de control y representa el salto de línea. Aparte, como la cadena de salto de línea varía según el SO (para Linux es `\n`, para Windows es `\r\n`), en algunos editores más básicos puede que veas cosas raras, pero hasta donde yo sé los editores de los navegadores trabajan con ambos indistintamente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función JSTL replace para sustituir cadenas del siguiente modo:

declaras la variable con el texto que quieres sustituir

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("carriagereturn","\n"); %>
```

y después haces la sustitución

```
${fn:replace(requestScope.msjok,carriagereturn,"<br/>")}
```